# Javascript confirm dialog coming up twice; Jumping back after clicking Element

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Beginner here, so please be gentle.

I'm trying to ask the User for confirmation. When he accepts, my javascript invokes a Button to run some code behind. The code behind will run a JavaScript function which alerts, just so I can see if it all works. What happens is, that after my first `confirm()` dialog, a second dialog appears. After confirming again, the code runs and my second JavaScript function confirms by alerting. But after I press okay on that, the whole thing jumps back to my first function and I get into a loop!

**ASPX:**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ConfirmComputerOverwrite(ComputerName) {          
    if (confirm("Overwrite present computer " + ComputerName + " ?"))
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
    document.getElementById("Test").click()
}

function allworkedout()
{
    alert("asdf");
}
```

**Code behind:**

```
public string ComputerName = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ComputerName = "Computer1";
    this.ComputerName = ComputerName;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("ConfirmComputerOverwrite('" + ComputerName + "');");

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ConfirmComputerOverwrite", sb.ToString(), true);
}

protected void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("allworkedout();");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "allworkedoutID", sb.ToString(), true);
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: use !(page.isPostback) in page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using ajax, the whole page is reloaded after click, so your javascript is executed again, prompting for confirmation, etc...

Comment: I see, thank you. 

Do you know any good resources, that help me finding out what to do?